# Have there been any studies to answer whether teachers having favourite students (publicly) reduces overall learning?

Tags: education, learning

I'm working on a presentation for class debunking myths about learning. The way I'm going about this is proof-checking some advice given by teaches in general such as finding a learning style. Now I'm seeing if teachers should not have a favourite student. Have there been any studies on this to debunk/prove this statement?

Also, the about section is kind of vague so am I in the right stack exchange?

Comment: Verbatim from the help center: *If you have a question about...

Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
Inner workings of research departments
Requirements and expectations of academicians
University-level pedagogy
... then you're in the right place!*

Comment: *However, please do not ask questions about

Undergraduate admissions
Undergraduate life and culture (sports, nightlife, dorms, leaving the nest, etc.)
Suggestions or recommendations for a university, journal, or research topic (a "shopping question")
Preparation for a non-academic career ("What graduate degree will help me get a job as X?")
The content of your research, rather than the process of doing research*

Comment: @BryanKrause It seems to me that this falls under "university pedagogy".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Possibly, but I didn't get the impression that the OP is asking from the perspective of university pedagogy.

Comment: @BryanKrause "How does this attitude of the professor affect student learning" isn't part of pedagogy?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Specifically the OP used the word 'teacher' which of course can be interpreted more broadly but is most often used to refer to educators in highschool and below. It's also asked from the perspective of someone preparing a presentation for class rather than an educator trying to improve their practice, which seems to trend a bit in the direction of homework help. I would say that often part of the pedagogy of assigning a presentation includes finding resources to support claims in that presentation.

Comment: Homework- no. Undergraduate- yes.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'd like to make sure I understand fully. Because someone could use the information in a presentation, it makes it not about university pedagogy? Can I get all the questions on this site closed by commenting "thanks, I'm doing a presentation on this subject and you were very helpful"? (As for the word "teacher"... I'd rather not say anything.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I am very wary of questions that ask for references and do not show substantial prior work. Some of this might come from my participation on other stacks that more commonly attract people trying to get SE to do their course assignments for them. I think the framing of questions can certainly influence whether or not they are on-topic - sometimes I choose to help askers by editing their question to avoid closure due to how a question is framed.

Comment: May I point out that I tried to search online for it yet couldn't find it. AND this is voluntary not compulsory.

Comment: Some papers: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=teacher%27s+pet&btnG=